# 2 lines of text. 1st line can have max 2 lines. Bottom needs to ALWAYS be on second line, wrapped behind line 1. CSS only solution please

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
<div class="link">
   <i class="icon" />
   <div class="text-wrapper">
       <span class="label">Some label which can span at most 2 lines</span>
       <span class="subtext">(optional)</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**One way of displaying is:**

[image: text on 2 separate lines]

*Notice how the label wraps to the second line while the subtext is trailing behind it.*

---

**The other way of display is:**

[image]

*Notice how the label here is not long enough to wrap, but the subtext is still on the second line.*

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve the above with HTML/CSS only?  Feel free to ignore the icon in the solution. I have that already.  Thanks in advance.

The code I have so far...

```
.link {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding-left: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}
.icon {
  padding: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.label { 
  margin-right: 4px; 
  color: #007dbb; 
}
.subtext { color: #686868; }
```

Comment: hi please add the css you use so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Set the first span as `display: block;` (see css for `label`-element). That will display the first span as a block element, forcing the second span to begin on a new line.

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding-left: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}
.icon {
  padding: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.label { 
  display: block;
  margin-right: 4px; 
  color: #007dbb; 
}
.subtext { color: #686868; }
```

```html
<div class="link">
    <i class="icon">Icon</i>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <span class="label">Some label which can span at most 2 lines</span>
        <span class="subtext">(optional)</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi @SimonF, thanks for trying, but your solution does not satisfy the requirements. See the first screenshot in the original question.

Comment: @JohnFu Doesn't your own code fulfills the first scenario? Also it wasn't clear that you wanted solutions to 2 problems not 1. Please clarify your question with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two separate `span` for `title` and `subtitle`. You can have one parent for title and add `subtitle` span inside it.

```css
.link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.link i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.text-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 175px;
}
.text-wrapper p {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.text-wrapper .subtitle {
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
    <i class="icon">Icon</i>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <p class="title">Some label which can span at most 2 lines
          <span class="subtitle">(optional)</span>
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: While downvoting, please leave the reason as well. So that I would know what went wrong.

Comment: Tested this and it doesn't work, remove away some of the text to make it really short and the word 'optional' doesn't form in a new line.

Comment: @Gosi - It is not necessary that the optional will always be on new line. If sufficient space is available, it gets wrap around title text. I'am not blaming, I'am asking to one who have downvoted.

Comment: It is part of his requirement which he has stated. "Notice how the label here is not long enough to wrap, but the subtext is still on the second line."

Comment: If this is the requirement, then i think it is difficult to manage with css, whereas it could be managed with javascript.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your effort.  However, @random , your solution's output is no different to my current state.  How would you do it with javascript then?  I don't want to have to calculate the width/height of the title all the time.  Because it needs to be responsive, and I don't want to recalculate everytime resize happens.